# XMLReader: Get value of child node if another child node contains a special string

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I have a XML structure (only a snippet) as follows:

```
<ttOutput>
    <ttOutputRow>
       <cKey>key</cKey>
       <cValue>value</cValue>
    </ttOutputRow>
    <ttOutputRow>
       <cKey>findMe</cKey>
       <cValue>value</cValue>
    </ttOutputRow>
    <ttOutputRow>
       <cKey>key</cKey>
       <cValue>value</cValue>
     </ttOutputRow>
</ttOutput>
```

For this I want to use `XMLReader` to keep memory low. I'm looking for *cValue* if *cKey* is *findMe*. How can I get this value?

This is what I tried:

```
using (var stream = new StreamReader(path))
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.IsStartElement())
        {
            Console.WriteLine (reader.Name);
            if (reader.Name == "ttOutputRow") {
                XmlReader subreader = reader.ReadSubtree ();
                while (subreader.Read ()) {
                    if (subreader.Name == "cKey" && subreader.Value == "findMe") {
                        subreader.ReadToNextSibling ("cValue");
                        Console.WriteLine ("found");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Perhaps I can use `ReadToDescendant(String)` or `ReadSubtree()` here, but I don't know how to use it correctly.

**Edit:**

This seems to be another option using `ReadToDescendant`:

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing ("ttOutputRow");
    do {
        if (reader.ReadToDescendant ("cKey")) {
            if (reader.ReadInnerXml() == "findMe") {
                reader.ReadToNextSibling ("cValue");
                Console.WriteLine ("found");
            }
        }
    } while (reader.ReadToFollowing ("ttOutputRow"));
}
```

I also found out that you can only use `ReadInnerXml()` one time.

Comment: I think you would be better off using XPath, have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I don't want to load the whole file into memory, because it is to big for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `subreader.Value` when the reader points to the *child* text node instead of pointing to the *parent* element node. You can also use `ReadInnerXml()` to get text value of an element node provided that the element doesn't have child element, for example :

```
if (subreader.Name == "cKey" && subreader.ReadInnerXml() == "findMe") 
{
    subreader.ReadToNextSibling("cValue");
    Console.WriteLine ("found: {0}", subreader.ReadInnerXml());
    //output:
    //found: value
}
```

Comment: Does using a *subreader* increases the need for memory because two readers are active at the same time? Do you think reading the file directly instead of using a `StreamReader` is better (more memory efficient)? I've updated my question with an example using `ReadToDescendant`. Is using `ReadToDescendant` or `ReadSubtree` better? Is there a possibility to stack `ReadInnerXml` into a stream so that not everything is hold in memory?

Comment: Should I check for `reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element`? Or isn't this necessary?

Comment: Since most of the XmlReader methods being used in your code receives element name as parameter -f.e `ReadToDescendant("elementName")-, check for `NodeType` isn't necessary I think -the type in that case must be `XmlNodeType.Element`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you had a chance to look on my other questions too?